# How to add text to the same <figure> under the image?

Tags: html, css, figure

So, here is my code, but problem is that text is right to the image, but not under the image. How to add it correctly?

```css
figure { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: justify;
}

figure img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/books/2019/Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis.jpg" alt="Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis"/>
            <figcaption>Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
body { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: justify;
 }
figure > img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  max-width: 100%;
}
figcaption {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis"/>
            <figcaption>Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @susanta96 ! i copy your imageplaceholder for my answear ;-)

Comment: Well this works, thanks, just right now ir has other problem, if I use one more figure so empty space between them are big, maybe you know how to lower that?

Comment: Put the question with the example i would try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the `display: grid;` from the figure's css.
Just like this:

```
 figure {
     grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
     grid-gap: 20px;
     align-items: stretch;
     text-align: justify;
 }
```

Comment: This one also resize my image, don't leave it by 200ox

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to come up with the grid system to do that. Here is a simple varainte that does what you want.

```css
figure { 
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: justify;
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}
figure img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  max-width: 100%;
}
.figcaption {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <figure class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis"/>
            <figcaption>Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: This one also resize image size :(

Comment: @raipav1 What do you mean with "This one also resize ..."? I updated my answear and set width 200px; to the img. Did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Making the figure display flex will do it.

Here's a simple example.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

figure img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/300" alt="A view" />
    <figcaption>Rhonda Byrne - Paslaptis</figcaption>
  </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well this one resize image :(

Comment: What size do you want the image to be? Just as an example I've unset the default browser margin/padding settings for body and other elements and set the width to widest possible within the body. You can of course change that to be what you want, for example as a % of the body width.